# Skype new Beta version is not working

Tags: 14.04, skype, beta

I have recently installed new skype version 5.3.0.1 in my **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** this way:

- Download `skypeforlinux-64.deb` file from https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/
- install it using right click and select Open with Ubuntu Software Center.

It installs the package successfully, but when I clicked on Skype icon to open it, it's not opening. It's not giving any error or anything.

[image: i have tried sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb too to do it]

Comment: I run this on 16.04 without any issue. Have you tried installing via `sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb`? Perhaps there is something going wrong during installation that you're not being notified of.

Comment: i have a skypeforlinux-64.deb downloaded file from https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/ link of skype , and i am installing it by Right Click on this file and Open with Ubuntu Software Center and then select install. its showing installed successfully, and when i click on icon to launch nothing is happened. even not showing any problem.

Comment: Like I said, try installing it from terminal. It could be that the software center is not showing you an error if there is one happening during install

Comment: i have tried but situation is same.

Comment: Can you post the output of the installation command to your question? I have had no problem getting this up and running on a 14.04 Xubuntu installation.

Comment: i have updated my Question with image of output of this command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60295/discussion-between-b-laoshi-and-aniruddh-parihar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Open from commandline**

I don't know what was causing this problem on the OP's machine, but after chatting with him, a solution that worked for him was to run `skypeforlinux` from the command line.

Comment: yes i have followed some instruction by b_laoshi and finally got a solution. thanks man it works now.

Comment: Before it, upgrade skype if needed...

Answer (score 2):

I have found your same situation, the reason is because when you install a package with `dpkg` it doesn't automatically install its dependencies.
To fix your installation it is enough to call `aptitude` to correct missing dependencies using `apt-get install -f`.